# Make android project in old template in new version of ADT and SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, android-appcompat

In consider of the problems i had when updating ADT and SDK, like Unwanted appcompt_* project and ... that i created a ticket here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68592

1. The Adt doesn't create default hello world project: 
   http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66647
2. With update this problem solved but another problem produced. create unwanted project while make a new project:
   http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66975

so i found a solution to make project like before in old template see answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that i share here and just follow these steps:

1. In Adt create android project and in first wizard choose API 14 as min SDK version
   [image]
2. Press Next until you reach to last wizard and choose Main for all three fields 
   [image]
3. Open Main.java file and delete the lines highlited in red:
   [image]
4. Now your file becomes to this and error disappear:
   [image]
5. Also you have one main layout xml file:
   [image]
6. Done. Now your project works like before

Answer (score 0):

Really? is this a 'solution' for the actual problem? What if my project needs to use ActionBar and other items from the Material Design package?

Comment: It's another problem.it's just for someone used to use old template or someone is new and tutorials is in old template.for that purpose then you should not touch anything :-)